# Sorting array of objects by the ascending order of values related to another value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I am looking to sort a JSON array of objects by the ascending order of values related to another value. Sounds confusing because it is. I have properties 'column' and 'order' in each object in an array. I need the order to be like:
lowest number in column 1, lowest number in column 2, lowest number in column 3, second lowest number in column 1, second lowest number in column 2, second lowest number in column 3 and continue on. This is easy when 'order' has the exact same values, you can use a sort function like:

```
function sortCourses(a, b){
    if (a.order == b.order) {
        return (a.column - b.column);
    } else {
        return (a.order - b.order);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't always have them setup like that. Here is an example array:

```
[
    {
        column: 2,
        order: 5
    },
    {
        column: 1,
        order: 1
    },
    {
        column: 3,
        order: 2
    },
    {
        column: 3,
        order: 1
    },
    {
        column: 1,
        order: 4
    },
    {
        column: 2,
        order: 1
    },
    {
        column: 3,
        order: 3
    },
    {
        column: 1,
        order: 3
    },
    {
        column: 2,
        order: 3
    },
    {
        column: 1,
        order: 2
    }
]
```

After sorting, I need this array to look like:

```
[
    {
        column: 1,
        order: 1
    },
    {
        column: 2,
        order: 1
    },
    {
        column: 3,
        order: 1
    },
    {
        column: 1,
        order: 2
    },
    {
        column: 2,
        order: 3
    },
    {
        column: 3,
        order: 2
    },
    {
        column: 1,
        order: 3
    },
    {
        column: 2,
        order: 5
    },
    {
        column: 3,
        order: 3
    },
    {
        column: 1,
        order: 4
    }
]
```

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: an array has `sort` method accepting 1 argument of comparing function which looks similar to what you provided. However it looks like it's for ascending sorting. You need to swap the minuends and the subtrahends (in both subtraction in your comparing function).

Comment: I am using the sort method, sorry should have mentioned that. That comparing function I provided puts them in order [1,1],[2,1],[3,1], but doesn't know to put [2,3] after [1,2] since it is looking to put [2,2] beside it, which doesn't exist. If what you are proposing would do this, can you post an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be a little faster, but hopefully easy to follow.

```
const data = [
    { column: 2, order: 5 }, { column: 1, order: 1 }, { column: 3, order: 2 },
    { column: 3, order: 1 }, { column: 1, order: 4 }, { column: 2, order: 1 },
    { column: 3, order: 3 }, { column: 1, order: 3 }, { column: 2, order: 3 },
    { column: 1, order: 2 }
];

// Sort by order.
data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return (a.order - b.order);
});

// Group by column.
const groups = data.reduce(
  function (acc, value) {
    if (!acc[value.column]) {
      acc[value.column] = [];
    }
    acc[value.column].push(value);
    return acc;
  }, {});

// Get sorted columns.
const cols = Object.keys(groups).map(Number).sort();

// Loop over columns taking lowest value until we're out of values.
const out = [];
while (out.length < data.length) {
  cols.forEach(
    function (col) {
      if (groups[col].length) {
        out.push(groups[col].shift(0));
      }
    });
}

console.log(out);
```

Comment: I'm not sure about how the array in Javascript is different from what such as in C#, but looks like using `.shift()` to modify an array will require more calculation internally. Unless array in Javascript is just like a special object where the indices are just keys. However the code like this is shorter and cleaner but you said ***could be a little faster*** - that I'm afraid we may need some actual benchmark testing (between using `.shift` and finding the max length of all grouped arrays before using `for-loop` not `forEach`).

Comment: I've just thought of another approach in which we don't need to find the max length as well as using `.shift`. Looks like it's better than finding the max length.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly long winded way, but all I do is just group each 'group' (columns) into an object, pushing their orders into an array. Then I just sort them and paste them in.

```js
var array = [
    {
        column: 2,
        order: 5
    },
    {
        column: 1,
        order: 1
    },
    {
        column: 3,
        order: 2
    },
    {
        column: 3,
        order: 1
    },
    {
        column: 1,
        order: 4
    },
    {
        column: 2,
        order: 1
    },
    {
        column: 3,
        order: 3
    },
    {
        column: 1,
        order: 3
    },
    {
        column: 2,
        order: 3
    },
    {
        column: 1,
        order: 2
    }
];

var new_array = {}

for (let item of array)
{
  if (item.column in new_array)
  {
    new_array[item.column].push(item.order);
  }
  else
  {
    new_array[item.column] = [item.order];
  }
}

let max = 0;
for (let key in new_array)
{
  max = (max < new_array[key].length) ? new_array[key].length : max;
  new_array[key].sort();
}

var final = [];

for (let i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
  for (let key in new_array)
  {
    if (i < new_array[key].length)
    {
      final.push({column: key, order: new_array[key][i]});
    }
  }
}


console.log(final);
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked, but created a new array with just those properties only. I have upvoted the answer, but chose the other answer because it kept the object in tact.

Comment: ah didn't realise you needed it in tact, simply just clone the object :)